# How to create multiple groups from a single selection in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to select all events with a certain type from an events collection and then return 2 different groups using a single selection.

For example I currently have the following 2 selections:

```
const sessions = await Event.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      isAdmin: { $ne: true }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$sessionId'
    }
  }
]);

const users = await Event.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      isAdmin: { $ne: true }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$userId'
    }
  }
]);
```

I would like to achieve an end result of:

```
{
  numberOfSessions: sessions.length,
  numberOfUsers: users.length
}
```

By using a single query.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation pipeline which will provide the capability to create multi-dimensions data within a single stage.  For Eg:

```
const sessions = await Event.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      isAdmin: { $ne: true }
    }
  }, {
    $facet: {
        sessions: [{
            $sortByCount: "$sessionId"
        }],
        users: [{
            $sortByCount: "$userId"
        }]
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I will get back to it in a few days and will let you know how it goes.